# Cannot highlight ABPersonViewController property

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I can't seem to get ABPersonViewController to highlight the property I want. The controller displays fine with the correct person. The phoneNumberIdentifier is a reasonable value (0 or 1 depending on the contact) and returns the correct phone number programatically.

```
ABPersonViewController *personViewController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
personViewController.displayedPerson = personRef;
[personViewController setHighlightedItemForProperty:kABPersonPhoneProperty withIdentifier:phoneNumberIdentifier];
personViewController.allowsEditing = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:personViewController animated:YES];

[personViewController release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call

```
[personViewController setHighlightedItemForProperty:kABPersonPhoneProperty withIdentifier:phoneNumberIdentifier];
```

*after* you push the controller on the navigation controller.

And I'm afraid this is not the only peculiarity with the AddressBook framework...